# Comparing game objects Augmented reality game, Unity, Vuforia, C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm currently making AR card game where you need to pick up pair of same animation, projected on gaming card.
There are 16 different gaming cards, each 2 of which have same animation projected on them using Vuforia.
2 gaming cards can be tracked simultaneously. How do I compare if animation on both cards that are being tracked, are same?
I am newbie at coding but need this to be done.

```
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)

    {
        activeTrackables = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours ();
        MatchCount.cardCount++;
        if (MatchCount.cardCount == 2) { //if there are 2 tracked cards
            //Compare them
            if ( /* first projected animation */ == /* second projected animation */) {
                MatchCount.matches--;

            }



            matchText.text = "number of matches: " + MatchCount.matches;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MatchCount.cardCount--;
        if (MatchCount.cardCount < 0) {
            MatchCount.cardCount = 0;
        }
        matchText.text = "number of matches: " + MatchCount.matches;
    }
}
```

Comment: First you'll need two objects to compare. In your code example, there's not even one, unless you're talking about the current `transform` or `gameobject` for one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the Gameobjects into the code as a Gameobjects array. Then try using vuforias on tracker lost and found to set variables as the 'active' cards / image targets at runtime.

Once you know which are enabled you could compare the cards and find the matches you want.

Here's a link to vuforias board on finding the active target.

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/active-script-when-image-target-detected

And here's a guide

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-do-i-get-list-active-trackables